# Compose cannot access Hilt View Model after popping the navigation stack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have this code in my app:

```
@Composable
fun LogInScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    val backStackEntry = remember(navController.currentBackStackEntry) {
        navController.getBackStackEntry(MainAppNavOptions.AuthScreen.name)
    }
    val viewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(backStackEntry)
    ...
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.isUserSignInState.value){
        if (viewModel.isUserSignInState.value){
            navController.navigate(MainAppNavOptions.MainScreen.name){
                popUpTo(MainAppNavOptions.MainScreen.name){
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So here I'm getting my shared view model for the auth screens, and then I'm navigating to my main screen after successful login.

But it seems like to `LogInScreen` function runs again, and because I'm popping the back stack, it cant get the view model and throws an error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with route AuthScreen is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is Destination(0x532bad98) route=HomeScreen
at androidx.navigation.NavController.getBackStackEntry(NavController.kt:2440)
at com.elog.findnchat.ui.auth.login.LogInScreenKt.LogInScreen(LogInScreen.kt:55)
at com.elog.findnchat.ui.navigation.NavGraphKt$authScreens$1$2.invoke(navGraph.kt:204)
at com.elog.findnchat.ui.navigation.NavGraphKt$authScreens$1$2.invoke(navGraph.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:138)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:320)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:318)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:318)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:302)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:138)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$4.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:780)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$4.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:769)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:117)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedEnterExitImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:941)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedVisibility(AnimatedVisibility.kt:607)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:757)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:740)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt.AnimatedContent(AnimatedContent.kt:794)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:280)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$16.invoke(Unknown Source:27)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$16.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:169)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2468)
2023-08-28 19:15:51.868  7084-7084  AndroidRuntime          com.elog.findnchat                   E      at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2737)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3352)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3303)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:781)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1097)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:569)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:537)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@9e62ed5, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@70506ea, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@83b6ddb, AndroidUiDispatcher@f28b078]
```

Some notes:

- yes, it's working if I'm not popping the stack, but it's neccery
- I've tried adding `if (viewModel.isUserSignInState.value) return` and it's working, but I dont think that it's the best way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remember(navController.currentBackStackEntry)` is the wrong key to be using, since that field is immediately invalidated as soon as you pop.

You should be using the `navBackStackEntry` that is given to you by the `composable` function when building your graph - this ensures that recompositions due to the exiting transition still retain their state even while the pop is happening.

By using the right key, the `getBackStackEntry` call won't be called again while you are exiting, allowing to you continue to use that data while your screen exits.

Comment: thank you. but what's the difference between passing the ``backStackEntry`` and getting it from the nav controller?

Comment: Like the answer says, a pop is not an instantaneous thing - the old screen (and the `backStackEntry` associated with it) continues to exist even after the `currentBackStackEntry` is updated to where you are going to. They're only the same until you `navigate` or `popBackStack` to go somewhere else.